# Jenkins plugin manager says 500 internal server error

Tags: jenkins-plugins

1. I was told that a job cannot config the email notification, jenkins says 500 internal server error.
2. I found out that the problem was about the `email-ext` plugin. The default Mailer worked fine. Any job using the `email-ext` plugin cannot save configuration, even no change of the configuration.
3. I could not find what happens, the jenkins log didn't say anything.
4. I update the jenkins(2.72, then 2.73), and update all the plugins. problem did not disappear.
5. I uninstalled the plugin `email-ext` and tried to reinstall, but then jenkins said `500`, so I manually remove the `plugin/email-ext/` and the `...email-ext-config.xml`, then restart the jenkins.
6. now any operation with any plugin will return `500 internal server error`, even config the job with default mailer.

how could I fix this?